# Error while removing stopwords text in Python

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from text in Python using nltk.stopwords.

I used following code

```
[w for w in imdb['Comment'] if w not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

However, I got following error and stopwords are not removed.

```
C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1:     UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to     Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Then it says

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

and gives text back without dropping the stopwords.

The database I was working is IMDB database containing rating and comments. I have input file as follows.

imdb= pd.read_csv("C:\Users\XYZ\Text Analytics\imdb.csv")

Do I need to have some encoding while inputting file? What could be the issue? Any help welcome.

Thanks
Nin

Comment: Can you add the code in this post?

Comment: Providing real examples that actually reproduce the problems you are trying to solve makes it much easier to address the problems. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Making a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please post a bit more of the code

Comment: Yes, you need to decode the input you get from IMDB. However, this is not that easy with the csv module in Python 2. Since you're apparently a Python beginner: why don't you just switch to Python 3? There, handling encoding is much clearer, and you are less likely to get an obscure warning when things go wrong. Also, Python 3's csv module works with unicode natively.